# Cual es la diferencia entre Parsing y Casting?

Tags: java

hasta ahora tengo entendido que ambos son diferentes, pero estoy un tanto confundido de cuando utilizarlos o como usarlos bien. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El **casting** consiste en la conversión de tipos de datos similares (compatibles) entre sí, generalmente a través de la herencia. Por ejemplo:

```
interface Mascota {
    // contenido...
}

class Gato implements Mascota {
    // contenido...
}

class Perro implements Mascota {
    // contenido...
}

void prueba() {
    Gato gato = new Gato();
    Perro perro = new Perro();

    // Ambos son mascotas, por tanto, se puede hacer casting a Mascota.
    Mascota mascota1 = (Mascota) gato;
    Mascota mascota2 = (Mascota) perro;
}
```

Por otra parte, el **parsing** consiste en analizar el formato de una sentencia de texto, y obtener información si el formato es correcto. Por ejemplo:

```
    String str1 = "123";
    String str2 = "12t";

    // No se producen excepciones debido a que el formato de 'str1' es correcto (es un número entero).
    int n1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
    // Se producirá una excepción ya que 'str2' no tiene el formato esperado (número entero).
    int n2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);
```

Otro buen ejemplo del *parsing* son los lenguajes de programación: el compilador o intérprete realiza un análisis gramatical *(parsing)* para comprobar que la sintaxis sea correcta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora entiendo mejor!